# CMake: Create binary foo + library libfoo?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

In my CMakeLists.txt I want to create a binary named foo and a library named libfoo(.a|.so).

So I have tried using the following code:

```
add_executable(foo ${BIN_SRC})
add_library(foo ${LIB_SRC})
```

But unfortunately the code above fails with the error message:

```
Make Error at CMakeLists.txt:156 (add_library):
add_library cannot create target "foo" because another target with
the same name already exists.  The existing target is an executable created
```

It is abovious that I have 2 targets named foo in my CMakeLists.txt which is causing the error. I could e.g. fix the bug using:

```
    add_library(libfoo ${LIB_SRC})
```

But then my library gets named liblibfoo(.a|.so) which is not what I want!?

Answer (score 3):

Name of the executable/library *file* isn't forced to be the same as the *target*. You may adjust name of the file created using [OUTPUT_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html) target's property:

```
add_library(libfoo ${LIB_SRC})
set_target_properties(libfoo PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME foo)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: So, please *accept* the answer to indicate it's solved.